# Generating more energy from a tree

Tags: dc-dc-converter

My son is doing a Science Fair project on dc voltage from trees. We are only getting about 1 volt when they are put in series. He's in 6th grade, what is a simple way to increase the voltage ?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you are doing.  It is very difficult to picture putting trees in series.

Comment: It's like the potato battery. A copper nail, zinc coated nail and wire connecting them in series. The voltage increases and remains stable but with several wired together it's still only about 1 volt.

Comment: _"The voltage increases and remains stable but with several wired together it's still only about 1 volt."_ - please tell us the voltages you get for each number of trees in series. Also, **exactly** what are you using to measure the voltage? Can you show us a photo of the setup with several trees?

Comment: He's using a Fluke 75iii multimeter. With 1 tree the volt is .458 volts. When we add 3 trees its .937 drops with distance then increases to 1.2 volts with 7 trees wired together. You guys are way above my knowledge

Comment: The simplest way is to add more trees. It's the only way to get more power too. Power is both voltage and current. Similar to how something heavy and fast has the most energy behind it.

Comment: if all the nails are in the same tree  you could have a short-circuit problem. using manyu different trees or cutting the tree into pieces could help.

Comment: Working out current paths in your wired forest is not a trivial problem. There are less complex ways to learn about series circuits versus parallel circuits.

Comment: are you wiring them correctly?

Comment: What wite are you using - it has resistance and may be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [voltage from trees](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0136639) is actually a thing. Who'd have thought.

This study suggest you need to use copper electrodes for the highest voltage. Power is not specified here.
Series connection of trees may not be possible because one of the electrodes is a ground rod.

To actually use this voltage you'd need an [energy harvesting circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_harvesting).  Of which there are some kits available. [Silabs](https://www.silabs.com/community/mcu/32-bit/knowledge-base.entry.html/2014/06/18/energy_harvestingso-MuUY) has one.

---

*I'm unsure if I'm allowed to share the pictures of the research site here, see for yourself:*

Hao Z, Wang G, Li W, Zhang J, Kan J (2015) Effects of Electrode Material on the Voltage of a Tree-Based Energy Generator. PLoS ONE 10(8): e0136639. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0136639

Answer (score 0):

> We are only getting about 1 volt when they are put in series.

The problem you face is the inner resistance of your “tree battery”. If you stack multiple tree batteries, the voltage sources stack up, but the inner resistances do so, too. That means the idle voltage of the stack may be 3V or more but as soon you put a load to it, it decreases to 1V or so because 2V are wasted at the inner resistances.

To decrease the inner resistance, you need more electrode surface and less electrode distance. If the nails as electrodes are set, wire multiple pairs of nails in parallel, too.

Also note the electrodes degrade pretty quickly. You want to scrub them pretty well —especially the zinc one— every few minutes of operation. Also use new drill holes each time – the electrolyte also degrades.

---

To add some theory, the energy isn't coming from the tree log at all. It comes from the zinc. The metal zinc is turned into “zinc rust” when the battery operates, and to turn the “zinc rust” into zinc again, you need a process using huge amounts of heat and carbon in a zinc works.

Extreme pollution hazard, as zinc ore typically has lots of arsenic in it. Pure poison.

So —don't do batteries, kids—, they aren't environmentally friendly. “Tree batteries” neither.

Comment: _"Extreme pollution hazard, as zinc ore typically has lots of arsenic in it. Pure poison."_ - and copper ore too. So don't do electronics, kids! https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2019/07/26/business/copper-markets-arsenic-problem-back/

Comment: The difference is clearly copper is meant to be recycled because of its high price, while zinc typically isn't.

Comment: Yet more copper is mined than zinc. (19 million tons vs 13 in 2017). It may be problem for the mining industry, but is not relevant to this question.

Comment: It's a science fair project for a 12 year old. He's trying to prove trees can produce energy and are a viable source to help prevent forest fires. So we are using 14 gauge coated wire. In the forest I own, trees are 10 to 12 feet apart. Just wanting to see if there's a simple dc booster I can help him build. I saw one that takes a bd139 transistor but I can't find that low volt transistor for sale.